# is it possible to set readonly properties within init-called blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm using the builder pattern to do something like this

```
- (instancetype)initUsingBlock:(void(^)(id mutableCopy))block
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self && block)
    {
        __block id mutableInstance = [self mutableCopy];
        block(mutableInstance);
        self = [mutableInstance copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and setting properties using blocks. <s>I'm doing this with the intention of not having to rewrite an `init` for every subclass of this one.</s> But those properties are `readonly` and trying to set them within the block - called in another class - raises errors. Is there a right way to do this? `__block` doesn't seem to make a difference here.

**EDIT:** So, because of a comment down here, i became aware that it is not really a good idea to continue with what i was trying to do, so i dropped the builder pattern altogether, but i still wan't to know if it would be possible.

Comment: What could it mean to make a mutable copy of an object that hasn't been initialized (`[self mutableCopy]`)? Also, you know that `mutableCopy` doesn't magically make your class's properties read-write, right? Have you adopted `NSMutableCopying` and implemented `-mutableCopyWithZone:`? What does it do? Finally, with respect to "I'm doing this with the intention of not having to rewrite an init for every subclass of this one. […] Is there a right way to do this?", I'll respectfully say, no, there's no right way to do that. It's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using [`[setValue:forKey:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE) method of `NSObject`, but actually it's not a good practice doing that:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic,readonly) NSString *testProperty;

@end

@implementation TestClass

- (instancetype)initUsingBlock:(void(^)(id instance))block {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        block(self);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

...

```
TestClass *test = [[TestClass alloc] initUsingBlock:^(id instance) {
    if ([instance respondsToSelector:@selector(testProperty)]) {
        [instance setValue:@"It's working" forKey:@"testProperty"];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", test.testProperty);
```

Or:

```
TestClass *test = [[TestClass alloc] init];
if ([test respondsToSelector:@selector(testProperty)]) {
    [test setValue:@"It's working" forKey:@"testProperty"];
}
```

**PS:**  It works for all types inherited from NSObject or type which conforms NSKeyValueCoding protocol only.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but wouldn't that work in any case, even outside that init block?

Comment: It will work everywhere after `self = [super init]` call

Comment: Note that Key-Value Coding (what is used here) doesn't work for all types.